# Использование super в interface

Tags: java, дизайн-языка

Java, когда мы наследуем один интерфейс от другого, и в дочернем хотим вызвать метод родительского, то мы должны писать не super.метод (как в классах), а ИмяРодительского.super.метод? Если так, то почему?

```
 interface A {
    default public void method(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

interface B extends A {
    default public void method(){
       // не просто super.method();
       A.super.method();
    }
}
```

Из своих соображений, то потому что мы можем унаследовать еще 1 интерфейс с тем же методом, и компилятор уже не будет понимать, из какого родительского интерфейса метод я требую.

```
interface A {
    default public void method(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

interface C {
    default public void method(){
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

interface B extends A, C {
    default public void method(){
        // method() из С или A?
        A.super.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: неужели в java подвезли [ромбовидное наследование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)?

Comment: @KoVadim только если за него можно считать default-методы интерфейсов...

Comment: это не важно. Важно то, что это завезли:) И бедные программисты на java не знают что делать. А нужно просто не писать default реализации и проблемы не будет.

Comment: @Qada прямого подтверждения "да, из-за А или С" в документации и JLS я так и не нашел, но, надо полагать, дело именно в этом